# OpenCL: Kernel Code?

Tags: opencl

I am working on optimization of the ADAS algorithm which are in c++.

I want to optimize that algorithm using OpenCL tech.

I have gone through some basic doc of OpenCL.

I came to know the kernel code is written in C which is doing the optimization.

But I want to know how internally kernel is splitting the work into different workitems ?

How is the single statement is doing for loop task.

Please share your knowledge with me on OpenCL.

Tr,
Ashwin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all C code is not doing the optimization. Parallelism is. Optimization with OpenCL only works on algorithms that can heavily utilize parallelism. If you are using OpenCL like regular C you are probably slowing your algorithm down. This is because it takes lot of time to move data between host and device.

Secondly kernel is not splitting the work into different workitems. Instead programmer is splitting it by launching multiple kernels to run the same kernel code in parallel. You can set how many kernels you want launch by setting the `global_work_size` of the `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel`.

If you have a for loop where iterations are not dependent on each other, it could be a good part to optimize with OpenCL. It is also good if there is quite a lot calculations in that loop but not much data going into it and out from it. In that case you make the inner part of the loop into OpenCL kernel and launch it with a global_work_size that is equivalent to the for loop's total loop count.